# rbind using for loop outputting several matrices

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, output, rbind

So essentially I have two matrices:

```
A<-matrix(runif(10*10),ncol = 10) 
B<-matrix(runif(10*10),ncol = 10)
```

I am trying to create a for loop which will: 
a)remove the top row of matrix A and and add the top row of matrix B to the bottom of the new matrix A, to create a matrix a.

b)remove the 2 top rows of matrix A and and add the 2 top rows of matrix B to the bottom of the new matrix A,to create a matrix b

c)remove the 3 top rows of matrix A and and add the 3 top rows of matrix B to the bottom of the new matrix A, to create a matrix c 
. . .

I could write this manually like the code below shows, but I need to do this for a bigger matrix so it will take me much longer:

```
a<-rbind(A[2:10,],B[1:1,]) 
b<-rbind(A[3:10,],B[1:2,]) 
c<-rbind(A[4:10,],B[1:3,]) 
d<-rbind(A[5:10,],B[1:4,]) 
. 
. 
.
```

Here is my attempt at creating the for loop:

```
A<-matrix(c(rep(0,10*10)),nrow=10) 
n<-10 
for (i in 1:n-1){ 
  A<-rbind(R[(i+1):10,],ER[(1:i),]) 
}
```

This only outputs the n-1 matrix, but I would like all my matrices to be output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function does what you want for an arbitrary number of rows `nrows`

```
switch_matrices <- function(mat1, mat2, nrows){
  rbind(mat1[(1+nrows):nrow(mat1),],mat2[1:nrows,]) 
}
```

You can check that it works

```
all.equal(rbind(A[2:10,],B[1:1,]) ,switch_matrices(A,B, 1))
```

Make a list with all of your data frames in each list element.

```
l <- lapply(1:9, function(nrows) switch_matrices(A,B, nrows))
```

If you want to make each element of list `l` a separate variable in your global environment you can use

```
list2env(setNames(l,paste0("AB",seq_along(l))), envir = parent.frame())
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to create a function that takes as arguments the matrices and the rows. Then use `lapply` to iterate,

```
fun1 <- function(x, y, n) { rbind(x[n:nrow(x),], y[1:n-1,])}
lapply(2:nrow(A), function(i) fun1(A, B, i))
```

Comment: This seems vaguely familiar ;)

Answer (score 0):

I made a few change to your solution, and I used the variable `letters` which provide a list, for instance `letters[2]=b`.

To assign each new matrix to a dynamic variable, I used the function `assign`.

```
A<-matrix(runif(10*10),ncol = 10) 
B<-matrix(runif(10*10),ncol = 10) 
n<-nrow(A) 

for (i in 1:(n-1)){ 
  assign(letters[i],rbind(A[(i+1):10,],B[(1:i),]))
  paste(letters[i])
}
```